# How to create setup file for ios in windows

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I built apk of my app. But that runs only on android right. I want my app to run on iOS. That's why I developed the app in flutter. But I dont know how to 'build ios'. Can anyone tell me or guide me how can i do that. I tried searching on youtube but I couldnt find any videos. Can anyone share any video or clear document about it please.

I am using Android Studio on Windows
Note: Currently i dont want to release the app on App Store just I want to run in it on iphone.

Comment: You need Xcode on a Mac to build an iOS app

Comment: But flutter is supposed to build ios on windows right

Comment: No. You can use Flutter to develop cross-platform apps; apps that can be built for both Android and iOS but it still needs the iOS toolchain which is part of Xcode to actually build an iOS app.